# why the second space, statement count[length]++; not executed but switch to length = 0 statement?

Tags: c

my input is "Hoang...Dung''  (I change three space as ...)
after i debug i noticed that at the first space, state = 1, length = 0, max = 5
why the second space, statement count[length]++; not executed but switch to length = 0 statement?

```
#define IN  0
#define OUT 1

main()
{
    int state;
    int length, max;
    int count[8];
    int i,  j;
char c;
    length = 0;
    max = 0;
    state = OUT;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        count[i] = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
            state = OUT;

            if (length > max)
                max = length;

            if (length != 0)
                count[length]++;

            length = 0;
        } else if (state == OUT) {
            state = IN;
            length++;
        } else {
            length++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < max + 1; ++i) {
        printf("%2d: ", i);
        for (j = 0; j < count[i];   ++j) {
            putchar('#');
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Why? Because the first SPACE has set the value in `length` to be zero. So the condition `if( length != 0)` is false, so the  `count[length]++;` statement is not executed.

Comment: @Fe2O3 i debug, i see 2nd space count[length]++; statement is not executed but switch to length=0 statement is executed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because "switch to length=0" is not bound by any condition.  I am not getting what you are trying to achieve in your question, but put brackets after every `if`/`else` condition to better understand. Also add debug print output wherever you feel you are going wrong.

Comment: Why is that code abbreviated?

Comment: which one? elaborate your doubt

Comment: Why is that code abbreviated? 
why if (length != 0)
                 count[length]++;

             length = 0;
can be abbreviated to if (length != 0)
                 count[length]++;
else
             length = 0;

Comment: no both are different, if you are using it with an if/else condition only one of these statements will be executed(based on the condition). but now what you have done is you have placed length=0 outside the "if" parentheses so that it is independent of the condition in that if statement.